# K2 generate urls with date

Tags: joomla, k2

I create sitemap using one of sitemap generators. And see urls like index.php/en/about-us-en/itemlist/user/82-2015-10-13-06-57-48. How I can remove this urls from k2, I dont understand where came this urls.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that K2 has hidden links for users, where it lists the articles created by that user. I suggest you just do a find and replace on the sitemap before submitting it. Note that Google may already be indexing these links on your website.

You can add a rule in your .htaccess to have a 301 redirect of all ../itemlist/user/... links to your homepage.

Comment: Thank you, I know about what you say, but I think it can harm SEO

Comment: Unless you are using those links, it will not harm your SEO. If anything, it'll help your SEO standings.